# Overriding Conda Package Installation with Pip

Tags: pip, anaconda, python-cffi, cffi, accelerate

I'm trying to build the necessary dependencies to run some deep learning code and am running into issues with the c foreign function interface (cffi) installation. I need conda's accelerate package, however the package is built on top of an old version of cffi (1.10). I need it to be built on top of cffi version 1.11.2 which I can obtain through pip. Is there some way to exclude certain sub-dependencies when installing through conda? I'd assume this would mess up my accelerate install even if I were able to somehow replace the cffi dependency, but figured I'd see what my options are regardless